# Consulta pasaje de variables entre archivos PHP

Tags: php

Tengo la siguiente función, que recibe un servicio y lo retorna si la condición devuelve True , que en este caso verifica que el servicio corresponda al mes actual.

```
function serviciosDelMes($servicio){
        $mes = date('m');
        if( substr($servicio['fecha'],3,2)==$mes){
            return $servicio;    
        }  
    }
```

Luego esta función es llamada por otra, la cual la utiliza en `array_filter` para obtener la suma de todos los precios de los servicios del mes (la caja, digamos)

```
function get_monthly_cash_s(){
    $servicios = get_servicios();
    $serviciosMes = array_filter($servicios, "serviciosDelMes");
    $result = 0;
    foreach($serviciosMes as $t) {
        $result +=$t['precio'];
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Lo que yo quiero hacer es obtener, desde un `select` que se encuentra en otro archivo `php` (desde el cual hago la llamada a la función **get_monthly_cash_s()** ), el mes que el usuario quiera y así mostrar valores según el mes elegido. 
La pregunta en cuestión es:

Una vez que yo, desde el otro `PHP` obtenga la variable `$_POST['mesElegido']`, por ejemplo, *¿Como debe ser la llamada correcta para obtener ese valor en la variable $mes de la funcion serviciosDelMes?*

Si estoy un poco perdido, o lejos de un buen código pido disculpas. Hoy es mi día 13 con este lenguaje y estoy algo confundido. 
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. No entiendo mucho tu pregunta, además no describes el contexto conforme a la realidad. Dices que la función `serviciosDelMes` devuelve `true` lo cual no es cierto, viendo el código de la misma. Luego preguntas que cómo obtienes el valor de esa misma función `serviciosDelMes`, la respuesta a eso es: asignando una variable a la llamada a esa función, por ejemplo: `$laVariable= serviciosDelMes($parametro);` ahí, tendrás en `$laVariable` lo que retorne la función, peeeeero resulta que esa función no siempre devuelve algo. Tienes que dar coherencia al código.

Comment: Es cierto, no devuelve true. Si la condición es TRUE, retorna el Servicio. Disculpas por eso. El resto me parece claro, pero bueno, disculpas nuevamente. El valor que quiero obtener viene de un segundo archivo php donde no se encuentran estas dos funciones mencionadas. Es el value de un select que se manda de un formulario (no lo agregue porque aun no lo escribi, es un select con 12 options para cada mes). Quiero obtenerlo y guardarlo en la variable $mes de la primer funcion. Eso es todo, espero haber sido mas claro esta vez,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de ajax para realizar la consulta dependiendo del mes seleccionado

Ejemplo:

En html

```
<SELECT id="selmes">
   <option value="1">Enero</option>
.....
</SELECT>
```

en javascript

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>//se requiere 
$(document).on('change','#selmes', function(){
    var val_mes=$(this).val();//obtengo el valor seleccionado
    $.ajax({  
        url : 'get_monthlal_y_cash_s.php',   
        data : { mes : vmes },
        type : 'GET',
        //dataType : 'json',//si se requiere obtener un json
        success : function(res) {
          //res contiene el resultado
        },    
        error : function(xhr, status) {
            alert('un problema');
        },
        complete : function(xhr, status) {
            alert('Petición realizada');
        }
    });
});
```

en php

```
<?php
$mes=$_POST["mes"];
//tu funcion
function serviciosDelMes($servicio,$mes){       
    if( substr($servicio['fecha'],3,2)==$mes){
        return $servicio;    
    }  
}
function get_monthly_cash_s($mes){
  $servicios = get_servicios();
  $serviciosMes = serviciosDelMes($servicios, $mes);
  $result = 0;
  foreach($serviciosMes as $t) {
    $result +=$t['precio'];
  }
  return $result;
}
echo get_monthly_cash_s($mes);
?>
```